# how to suppress elisp evaluation output in yasnippet?

Tags: yasnippet

I'm trying to write a `yasnippet` template to write a standard header at the top of files. I have `(goto-char (point-min))` at the beginning of the template in order to move point to the top of the buffer; and while this works correctly, it outputs a `1`. This is presumably an affirmation of success from `goto-char`.

How would I suppress or eat that `1`?

Or is there a better way to position a `yasnippet` template at the top of a buffer?

Comment: Just wrap like `(progn (foo) nil)`

Comment: Sweet. `(progn (goto-char (point-min)) nil) works.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info